# Functions and generics

Tags: swift, swift2

I would like to implement a "naive" sort in swift. I am doing like this :

```
extension Array {
    func sort<Element: Comparable>(isOrderedBefore: (Element, Element) -> Bool) -> [Element] {

        var sortedArray : [Element] = []
        for x in self {
            for (index, value) in sortedArray.enumerate() {
                if isOrderedBefore(x, value) {

                }
            }
        }
        return sortedArray
    }
}
```

**I have a compilation error : "Cannot invoke isOrderedBefore with argument list '(Element, Element)**

If a remove the Comparable protocol, the code compiles but i can't implement the sorting function without the array elments been comparable.

This code compiles :

```
extension Array {
    func sort(isOrderedBefore: (Element, Element) -> Bool) -> [Element] {

        var sortedArray : [Element] = []
        for x in self {
            for (index, value) in sortedArray.enumerate() {
                if isOrderedBefore(x, value) {

                }
            }
        }
        return sortedArray
    }
}
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you think you *can't implement the sorting function without the array elments been comparable*? Since you give the user the capability to provide a custom compare function there is no need to specify that the generic needs to be comparable.

Comment: extension Array where Element: Comparable { ...

Comment: @luk2302 You are right, no need to conform to the Comparable protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic types of your sort function clash with the already existing generic type of the Array's `Element`. Extensions implicitly have the same type parameters as the base type. Your `sort` function does not need the type parameters because it already knows what an `Element` is.

Also, because you give it a function to do the comparison, you do not need the restriction of Element being `Comparable` in `isOrderedBefore` as long as you can figure out a way of comparing Elements yourself.

So I added enough code to your example to make it work (I also changed the name to not clash with the existing `sort()`).

```
extension Array {
    func mySort(isOrderedBefore: (Element, Element) -> Bool) -> [Element] {

        var sortedArray : [Element] = []
        for x in self
        {
            var inserted = false
            for (index, value) in sortedArray.enumerate() where !inserted
            {
                if isOrderedBefore(x, value)
                {
                   sortedArray.insert(x, atIndex: index)
                   inserted = true
                }
            }
            if !inserted
            {
                sortedArray.append(x)
            }
         }
        return sortedArray
    }
}
```

Now I can use it. If I have an array of Ints which conform to Comparable, I can use the comparison operators as `isOrderedBefore`

```
// Because I am using Int in the array, I can use > as the "closure" because
// its type is (Int, Int) -> Bool
let sorted = [1, 2, 6, 4, 3].mySort(>)

print("\(sorted)") // [6, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

If I have a type that is not Comparable, I need something different. So....

```
struct Person: CustomStringConvertible
{
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    var description: String { return "\(name) aged \(age)" }
}
```

Trying to use the comparison operator is an error because `Person` is not comparable

```
let foo = [ Person(name: "Fred", age: 12), 
            Person(name: "Alice", age: 20), 
            Person(name: "Pat", age: 15)].mySort(<) // Error!
```

But

```
let foo = [ Person(name: "Fred", age: 12),
            Person(name: "Alice", age: 20),
            Person(name: "Pat", age: 15)].mySort{ $0.age < $1.age }

print("\(foo)") // [Fred aged 12, Pat aged 15, Alice aged 20]
```

Answer (score 2):

a) an Array conforms to CollectionType and indirectly to SequenceType
b) there is the default implementation of sort as part of SequenceType

```
extension SequenceType where Self.Generator.Element : Comparable {
    /// Return an `Array` containing the sorted elements of `source`.
    ///
    /// The sorting algorithm is not stable (can change the relative order of
    /// elements that compare equal).
    ///
    /// - Requires: The less-than operator (`func <`) defined in
    ///   the `Comparable` conformance is a
    ///   [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_order#Strict_weak_orderings)
    ///   over the elements in `self`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func sort() -> [Self.Generator.Element]
}
```

and

```
extension SequenceType {
    /// Return an `Array` containing the sorted elements of `source`
    /// according to `isOrderedBefore`.
    ///
    /// The sorting algorithm is not stable (can change the relative order of
    /// elements for which `isOrderedBefore` does not establish an order).
    ///
    /// - Requires: `isOrderedBefore` is a
    ///   [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_order#Strict_weak_orderings)
    ///   over the elements in `self`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func sort(@noescape isOrderedBefore: (Self.Generator.Element, Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> [Self.Generator.Element]
}
```

so, if the default implementation is not enough for you ( if you have some special requirements about the order of elements that compare equal ) you can follow the same scenario

```
extension SequenceType where Self.Generator.Element : Comparable {
    public func mySpecialSort() -> [Self.Generator.Element] {
      ... 
    }
}
```

and / or

```
extension SequenceType {
    public func mySpecialSort(@noescape isOrderedBefore: (Self.Generator.Element, Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> [Self.Generator.Element] {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 2.0 you can create an extension for the array of comparable type like this:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Comparable {
    func dumbSort(isOrderedBefore: (Generator.Element, Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> [Generator.Element] {

        var sortedArray : [Generator.Element] = []
        for x in self{
            for (_, value) in sortedArray.enumerate() {
                if isOrderedBefore(x, value) {
                    // do what you planned to
                }
            }
        }
        return sortedArray
    }
}
```

Comment: No point in using `enumerate()` if you're going to ignore it's index output.